# Nothing happens if press on transparent part of uicollectionviewcell in iOS8 Today Extension

Tags: uicollectionview, ios8, transparency, uicollectionviewcell, ios8-today-widget

I have widget with collection of icons and these icons are on transparent background. UICollectionViewCell is also transparent. The problem is that if press on transparent part of the cell -

> (void)collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:

is not called.
But if change cell's backgroundView to black color with alpha = 0.01 everything works well. I have a feeling that alpha solution is not the best one. Am I doing something wrong or anybody have better solution?

[image: Collection views with alpha = 0.01]

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223537/ios-today-extension-table-view-rows-only-detects-taps-on-a-label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You NEED the 0.01 alpha workaround.

According to Apple's DTS, it is an iOS 8 bug.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the moment is to create a empty text label as a background view, or add it in the .xib file as a first view.