# UITableView in a Today Extension not receiving row taps

Tags: ios, ios8-today-widget

I have a iOS 8 app with a Today Extension. The extension has a UITableView in it and it is rendering correctly. However, didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't seem to get called reliably. I am guessing this is because Notification Center is a UIScrollView and embedding a UITableView in those causes some issues, but I am not sure.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223537/ios-today-extension-table-view-rows-only-detects-taps-on-a-label

Comment: i think the workaround mentioned as "possibly related" above and the answers below is not quite the answer to this question; i've tried the solutions mentioned, and for the problem that those answers are trying to solve, stretching the Label to cover the entire contentView works for me.  however, i also have the problem of, after scrolling the entire Today page, tapping on a tableView row doesn't work the first time, but does every time thereafter.  i think the guess that it's an anomaly of the tableView being embedded in the scrolling today extension page is correct.  haven't yet solved it.

Comment: I have the same issue after scrolling. It does not work even if you have 100% solid colours. I am sure this is Apple's bug.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: set the opacity to 0.01 like this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.01];
```

Comment: i've same issue, but this not worked on xcode 9. any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Swift 2.1 / iOS 9.1:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: (255.0/255.0), green: (255.0/255.0), blue: (255.0/255.0), alpha: 0.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a UITableView in an extension. The height of the extension's view was determined by a height constraint. The cells reacted to taps only sporadically.

What solved this problem was setting `preferredContentSize` instead of using a constraint.