# Open main app via today extension

Tags: swift, uitableview, xcode6, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I implemented added a today widget into my app. The today extension includes an UITableView. Now I'd like to open the app if a cell of the UITableView has been pressed. Does someone of you know how to do this?

Comment: Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019820/today-app-extension-widget-tap-to-open-containing-app

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Today extensions have access to an `NSExtensionContext` [which allows you to open an app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSExtensionContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSExtensionContext/openURL:completionHandler:). In your extension controller:

```
let myAppUrl = NSURL(string: "myapp://some-context")!
extensionContext?.openURL(myAppUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
    if (!success) {
        // let the user know it failed
    }
})
```

The success parameter is provided because the system may not be able to open a particular URL (say you want to launch "twitter://" but the user does not have the Twitter app installed. If you're launching your own app, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Since you said you want it to launch when the user taps a UITableViewCell, presumably you'd call it in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: I tried this already but the func `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` isn't working.

Comment: I tried this already but the func `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` isn't working.

Comment: There is a bug where tapping blank areas in `UITableViewCell`s does not result in table view callbacks. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223537.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The provided code by Christopher Pickslay works fine, you just need to add the following lines to the application's info.plist (open as a source code):

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.mikitamanko.myapp</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>some-context</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

right after the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
```

Here's the [complete guide](http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/02/15/swift-how-to-create-ios-today-extension-and-share-data-with-containing-app/) how to open the app or share Users Defaults with Extension and the containing app.